# vb.net reading xml file with elements in <>

Tags: xml, vb.net, vsto

I am trying to edit an XML file using vb.net. This XML file is for a miscrosoft outlook add in ribbon. I want to be able to edit the code so that users can add buttons to my addin (their version) I am somewhat new to VB and xml in general and I cannot seem to find how to do this. here is my current issue.

I can read and right files that look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customUI>
        <ribbon>
           <tabs>
              <tab>
                 <group>
                     <button>
                     </button>
                 </group>
              </tab>
           </tabs>
        </ribbon>
    </customUI>
```

But as soon as I add "elements?" within the node <> I can't seem to edit. Below is the xml that I cannot seem to figure out how to edit.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
        <ribbon>
           <tabs>
              <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
                 <group>
                     <button id="Add" label="AddNode" getImage="GetImage" onAction="RunAdd" visible="true" size="large" screentip="Add an XML file Node" />
                 </group>
              </tab>
           </tabs>
        </ribbon>
    </customUI>
```

here is what I have tried
1. I tried to rewrite my xml code so nothing was within the <> other than the node name. this caused errors with my buttons that i could not seem to resolve.
2. My current vb.net code looks like this

```
Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNode
MyXMLNode= MyXML.SelectSingleNode("/customUI/ribbon")
WriteLine("Hello World2")
If MyXMLNode IsNot Nothing Then
    WriteLine("Hello World")
    MyXMLNode.InnerText = "CreateTeset"
    Else
        WriteLine("Hello World3")
        'Do whatever 
    End If ' Save the Xml.
```

This code works to edit the first XML but not the second.

Based on the writeline's I know the problem is with this line because Hello World is not output but Hello World2 and 3 are.

```
MyXMLNode= MyXML.SelectSingleNode("/customUI/ribbon")
```

I tried code that was something like this (Note I am not sure that the below code is right because I cannot find the page that I got it from to confirm. It should have been right when I was using it though.

```
MyXMLNode= MyXML.SelectSingleNode("/customUI/ribbon['element']")
```

I have searched but I cannot find any one trying to read XML like this. I would be willing to rewrite the XML as well. Any help is appreciated.

Also here is what I want to be able to do. I want to be able to add/delete/edit buttons groups and tabs. An example would be I want to update the Label of a button from "something" to "something else"

EDIT:
How do I select the customUI node to edit xmlns for example

Here is what I tried

```
Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNode = MyXML.SelectSingleNode("/customUI")
Dim strValue As String = MyXMLNode.Attributes("xmlns").Value 'retursn "Add"
    WriteLine("Hello World2" & strValue)
    If MyXMLNode IsNot Nothing Then
        WriteLine("Hello World")

        MyXMLNode.Attributes("xmlns").Value = "CreateTest"

    Else
        WriteLine("Hello World3")
        'Do whatever 

    End If ' Save the Xml.
```

I get an error at the second dim line because the first dim line didn't do anything (IE it returns a null node)

Comment: The main difference I notice is the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"` on the root element. You will have to adjust your XPath expressions passed to `SelectSingleNode` to use a prefix and pass an `XmlNamespaceManager` binding the prefix to the namespace used in the XML.

Comment: Can you give an example I apologize but I am not really familiar with alot of this vocabulary. (No formal code background)

Comment: See the example in the documentation first, it covers exactly the case of a default namespace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9(v=vs.110).aspx saying "If your XML includes a default namespace, you must still add a prefix and namespace URI to the XmlNamespaceManager; otherwise, you will not get any nodes selected"

Comment: @MartinHonnen That solved my issue thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are simple ways to do this.
Reading Attribute:

```
Dim strValue as string = MyXMLNode.Attributes("id").Value 'retursn "Add"
```

Change Attribute:

```
MyXMLNode.Attributes("id").Value = "My New Value"
```

To add a new button:

```
MyXMLNode= MyXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("/customUI/ribbon/tabs/tab[idMso='TabAddIns']/group")

'Create a new node
XmlElement elem = MyXMLNode.CreateElement("button");

'Create Attribute
XmlAttribute typeAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("id");
typeAttr.Value = "Add";
elem.Attributes.Append(typeAttr);

'Add more attributes here

'Add the node to the document.
MyXMLNode.AppendChild(elem);
```

Comment: Thanks this definitely helps and I knew it would be simple I just could not find it. My problem still remains however using your code because I cannot seem to select a node. See my edit above for what I tried to do unsuccessfully